# Issue with clearing float in li element

Tags: html, css

Trying to reproduce the following in HTML & CSS:

[image]

Here's how I tried to structire it:

```css
.layout ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.layout ul > li:nth-child(1n) > img {
    float: left;
}

.layout ul > li:nth-child(2n) > img {
    float: right;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that when applying clearfix it doesn't help at all. The images seem to come on one row. Maybe is there something specific when it comes to li elements and clearfix? How this can be solved?

Comment: Of course you need to limit the width of the container, so that no more than two images fit next to each other, for this to work ... `.layout ul { width: 200px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply consider `text-align` property and some negative margin for the overlap (this will avoid you all the float issues)

```css
.layout {
  width: 200px;
}

.layout ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  position: relative; /* don't forget this to be able to use z-index */
}

.layout ul>li {
  text-align: left;
}

.layout ul>li:nth-child(2n) {
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 999; 
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of ***transform*** css property

```css
.layout ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.layout ul>li {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.layout ul>li>img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.layout ul>li:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/grayscale" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```